# How to deal with IAzure Interface while migrating from Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent to Azure.ResourceManager?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, nuget-package

I am migrating my source code to use Azure.ResourceManager package instead of Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent (which is deprecated).
My code uses IAzure interface like mentioned below:

```
/// <summary>
/// The azure context.
/// </summary>
private readonly IAzure azureContext;

this.azureContext = this.GetAzureForSubAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// method declaration here for GetAzureForSubAsync
private async Task<IAzure> GetAzureForSubAsync()
{
    // <some logic>
    return Azure.Configure()
        .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders)
        .Authenticate(new AzureCredentials(tokenCredentials, tokenCredentials, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud))
        .WithSubscription(this.subscriptionId);
}
```

I am not sure which Interface would provide me the equivalent logic in new package ie. Azure.ResourceManager

While pipeline build, I get this error:

```
##[error]src\Test\LoadTest\ARMLib\ARMExecutor.cs(16,21): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Rest' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

##[error]src\Test\LoadTest\ARMLib\ARMExecutor.cs(170,28): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAzure' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

##[error]src\Test\LoadTest\ARMLib\ARMExecutor.cs(26,26): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAzure' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have gone through documentations but I think I am not getting it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [ArmClient Class (Azure.ResourceManager) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.armclient?view=azure-dotnet) which is the alternative of IAzure in Azure.ResourceManager class:-

**Sample code [**here**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/resourcemanager/Azure.ResourceManager/README.md):-**

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;

ArmClient client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
string resourceGroupName = "siliconrg";
SubscriptionResource subscription = await client.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
ResourceGroupCollection resourceGroups = subscription.GetResourceGroups();
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await resourceGroups.GetAsync(resourceGroupName);
await foreach (VirtualMachineResource virtualMachine in resourceGroup.GetVirtualMachines())
{
    //previously we would have to take the resourceGroupName and the vmName from the vm object
    //and pass those into the powerOff method as well as we would need to execute that on a separate compute client
    await virtualMachine.PowerOffAsync(WaitUntil.Completed);
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**DevOps YAML pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

**Output:-**

[image]